# pagination with bootstrap 4 cards

Tags: php, html, sql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a sort of blog area on my website using bootstrap 4 cards, i fill my cards with data from my database. And i want to put the cards inside of a pagination with a category filter 
[image]

my category select is working fine, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to tackle the part for calculating how many rows and columns are supposed to be on the webpage. I know i can make a variable which holds the maximum amount of rows and columns and calculate the offset from that with the ceil function. Then put that into a SQL query  with the LIMIT being the offset and maximum items but I am not sure how this works with rows. this is the code i have at the moment. `

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            <li class="page-item disabled">
                <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
            </li><li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="blog.php?category=<?php if (isset($_GET["category"])){echo $_GET["category"];}?>&pagenumber=<?php // this is also where I'm stuck ?>">1</a>
</li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="blog.php?category=<?php if (isset($_GET["category"])){echo $_GET["category"];}?>&pagenumber=<?php // this is also where I'm stuck ?>">2</a></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="blog.php?category=<?php if (isset($_GET["category"])){echo $_GET["category"];}?>&pagenumber=<?php // this is also where I'm stuck ?>">3</a></li>
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

`

the category works so for example if i select category 2 the url will be

> http://localhost/HCDistributie/blog.php?category=2&pagenumber=

the only thing that is needed is to get the pagenumber.

this is my back-end code where i loop through each each item in the database and put that inside the card

```
    function getNews()
{
    // get current category
    if (isset($_GET["category"]) && is_numeric($_GET["category"])) {
        // bind get category to categoryId
        $categoryId = $_GET["category"];
        // if category is 1
        if ($categoryId == 1) {
            if (isset($_GET["pagenumber"]) && is_numeric($_GET["pagenumber"])) {
                $pageNumber = $_GET["pagenumber"];
                try {
                    $itemLimits = 9;
                    $rowLimit = 3;


                    $db = new Connection();

                    $database = $db->openConnection();

                    $stm = $database->query("SELECT * FROM blog where category = $categoryId");

                    $stm->execute();

                    $rowNews = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    foreach ($rowNews as $items) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="card-group">
                            <div id="classContainer" class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <img src=" <?php $items['img'] ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $items["title"]; ?></h5>
                                        <p class="card-text"><?php echo $items["content"] ?></p>
                                        <p class="card-text"><small
                                                    class="text-muted"><?php $items["author"]; ?></small>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }

                } catch
                (PDOException $e) {
                    echo sprintf("Something went wrong. $e->errorInfo");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I sort of have an idea what i should do the problem is I'm not sure how to apply that to my code, the tutorials i have read only deal with variable for max items while i have 2 max columns and max rows.
I am not sure how to calculate both of them separately.

This is the first time I worked with any sort of pagination so i apologize if some things seem weird and or stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not weird or stupid, first contact with pagination is always a hassle ;)

With bootstrap, you could get away with just knowing the maximal occurrences of your card records. You could wrap everything while using **rows** and **cols**, check out this example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      1 of 5
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      2 of 5
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      3 of 5
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      4 of 5
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      5 of 5
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tqhwomr7/)

Thanks to `.col-4`, you will always get three cards in a row. In your example:

```
<div class="card-group">
  <div class="row">
  <?php foreach ($item as $items) { ?>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card">
        // Your card content goes here, use $item
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

More importantly, it seems you writing something in plain PHP. If you want to go public, you should consider a framework that has already some validation capabilities and function helpers - even build in pagination! I would pick [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) for that.

EDIT:
Fixed mistake. Thanks @hakiko

Comment: `.col-3` will produce 4 equal columns. not three cards in a row. 12 / 3 = 4

Comment: part 1: Hey, thank you for you suggestion i implemented your example into my code and it works for the most part. The only thing that still bugs out is that all cards have cling onto the left side of the page instead of staying in the middle basically they go like this <|||  instead of this < | | | not sure how to properly word it but i hope you know what i mean. Also regarding your laravel comment i would love to the problem is that this project is from a intern that left the company and it's a mess but management does not allow me to use any sort of framework.

Comment: part 2: going on how would i loop through each item from the database so that each page will display 9 different items on each page?

Comment: Part 1 - First of all, remember to wrap the row in a container class like `<div class="container"> Everything here </div>`.
Second of all, it could be a styling issue. With the container, the cols should expand on the whole row. You could use class `container-fluid` also to get the whole width of the window.
Part 2 - Example SQL query with LIMIT & OFFSET: `SELECT * FROM blog where category = $categoryId LIMIT 9 OFFSET $offset`, where $offset = 9 * $pageNumber

Comment: Manged to fix the styling issue and added the container-fluid class which fixed the issue.  The query part is giving me a notice ( ! ) Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\laragon\www\HCDistributie\inc\get.php on line 53 this happens before the execute and it jumps straight to the catch.

Comment: Keep in mind I wrote the query more like in a pseudo-code, don't know the whole project. The error suggests you try to use an array object instead of an int. Check every variable with `var_dump()` to be sure of the types. To check just the query if it's right, you could run something like `SELECT * FROM blog where category = $categoryId LIMIT 9 OFFSET 0`. Also, not sure if $_GET does cast to int by itself, probably you will need to make sure with something like intval($_GET....) or (int) $_GET...

Comment: `var_dump()` both $_GET["category"] and pagenumber gave me a string i converted them to INT  with intval so that should be fixed now, the query on the other hand if i remove both LIMIT and OFFSET the error is gone. But if i remove either 1 or the other the error remains so not sure what the problem is in that. Also var_dumping $offset gives me an INT

Comment: Here is a [test sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a74d8/755/0). Keep in mind I assumed you are working with MySQL.

Comment: Fixed the error, i ran the debugger and the query shows this `"SELECT * FROM blog where category = 1 LIMIT 9 OFFSET 9" this gives me no data in the database but when i replace the offset with for example 4 it does get data from the database

Comment: Yeah, that seems correct then ;) As an example:
Page 1 - `... LIMIT 9 OFFSET 0`
Page 2 - `... LIMIT 9 OFFSET 9`
Page 3 - `... LIMIT 9 OFFSET 18`
etc.
As you can see, OFFSET is just the pageNumberIndex multiplied by the LIMIT you want on the page. LIMIT can be a constant in a variable like `$pageSize = 9;`, offset however needs to be calculated on every request while using the parameter from $_GET. Of course, checking if empty is also needed ;)